# 3 normals to the parabola

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

> Suppose there exists three normal lines from the point $(r, 0)$ to the
>   parabola $x = y^2$, and $r >  \frac{1}{2}$, one of which is the
>   x axis. Determine the value of r where the two other normal lines would be
>   perpendicular?

I found the $\frac{dy}{dx} (parabola)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} $ .

Thus gradient of normal, is $-2\sqrt{x}$, and the equation of normal is $y=-2\sqrt{x} (x-r) $.

If I equate the equation of normal with the parabola, 
I get $ \pm \sqrt{x}=-2\sqrt{x} (x-r) $, 
which solving will result in $x=\pm\frac{1}{2} +r$,

however I am stuck and I cannot find an exact value of r. Where did I go wrong and how should I have approached this question?

Comment: I can't find a value for $r$ either! Are there other conditions?

Comment: Your equation for the normal is not correct.  Notice that use are using $x$ to mean two different things; the equation you give is not the equation of a line.

Comment: @Raffaele no other conditions were given.

Comment: @MatthewConroy , sorry, I do not understand, isnt it => the equation of normal line using formula y-y1=m(x-x1) where m is the gradient of the normal obtained by -1/(dy/dx) and normal line passes through point (r,0)  ?

Comment: Try plotting the curve $y=-2\sqrt{x}(x-r)$ for any value of $r$.  You will see that it is not a line.  The problem is that the $x$ in the square root should be the $x$-coordinate of the point on the curve , while the other $x$ is the generic variable that you are relating to $y$ in the line equation.  The solution is to call this first $x$ something else, such as $a^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tangents and the normals form a square

The slope of a tangent is $m=\pm \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Which must be $\pm 1$

$-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=1\to x=-\frac{1}{4}$

The tangent has equation $y=x+\frac14$

the intersection with the parabola is

$$x=\left(x+\frac14\right)^2 \to x=\frac14;\;y=\frac{1}{2}$$

Normals have slope $m^{\perp}=\pm 2\sqrt{x}$

The normal has equation

$$y-\frac{1}{2}=-(x-\frac14)$$

the intersection with $x$ axis is $r=\frac{3}{4}$

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I missed out the fact that if one of the normal is on the x-axis and the other 2 are perpendicular then the gradients would be $\pm1$!

Answer (score 1):

In the diagram below, if the two normals are to be perpendicular, then we have a right triangle whose vertices are the three marked points, so that
$$(2a)^2 = 2((a-0)^2+(a^2-r)^2) = 2 a^2+2 a^4-4 a^2 r+2 r^2.$$
Also, since the lines are normal to the parabola, we see that the slope of the upper normal, which is $-2a$, must be equal to the slope of the line, so that
$$-2a = \frac{a}{a^2-r}.$$
Solving these two equations for $a$ and $r$ gives $r = \frac{3}{4}$ and $a = \pm\frac{1}{2}$.

[image]